# What are git's priorities when merging branches?

Tags: git

Suppose that I hav two git branches; `branch_one` and `branch_two`. If I `merge` these branches, will one of the two branches be considered more "up to date" that the other?
Is there a difference between `git merge branch_one branch_two` and `git merge branch_two branch_one`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's symmetric. Only during conflict it marks code as "their" "mine" differently. The merged branch tip will have changes from both branches, while other branch will be unchanged.

BTW, command `git merge b1 b2` does octopus merge of two branches into a current HEAD, so the command merges three branches. But I guess it's not what you meant, but just an illustration.